# Geokit helper usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, geokit

I'm trying to localize my users throught their IP address. As the docs say, a class method called `geocode_ip_address` has been mixed into the `ActionController::Base`. But there must be something I'm missing. Do I have to define a filter like this `before_filter :geocode_ip_address` to use it? (I want to know the location for every request done).

The documentation also talks about "A first-time lookup will result in the GeoLoc class being stored in the session as `:geo_location`" but I certainly don't have that key inside the session hash.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to prepend **before_filter** to geocode_ip_address, but rather just put that in your controller:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  geocode_ip_address

  def action
    if geo = session[:geo_location]
      # geo here is a Geokit::GeoLoc object
    end
  end
end
```

Note that if the geocoding fails **geo** will be nil.  If you're running in development you'll be trying to geocode 127.0.0.1, so you'll want to set your remote_ip in the request object.  I did so by adding this to the bottom of **config/environments/development.rb**:

```
class ActionDispatch::Request
  def remote_ip
    "x.x.x.x" # fill in your IP address here
  end
end
```

Comment: I had seen other posts saying to use **session[:geo_location]**, but there is also a **retrieve_location_from_cookie_or_service** helper method that may be used.

Comment: Thanks, the ActionDispatch remote IP workaround was quite useful.